# C++ OpenCV 3.4 : HOG detectMultiScale() / detect() issues

Tags: c++, opencv

I am having a problem with the detectmultiScale() function. I am developing a object recognizer of multiple objects (car, tree, building, ..). For this, I trained n binary SVM (object_i/no_object_i). On the test set (with patches of the same size) i get accuracy of around 90%, which is quite ok. However, when I use them to detect objects in a bigger image (i.e. with MultiScale() ) regardless of the model I use, i get a pretty window right in the middle of the image.

[image]

Do you have any Idea of what could be the issue here? I used the detect() function and in this case I get literally the exact opposite situation. squares everywhere.

[image]

I gave as function parameter a vector as well to get the confidence weights. However, the returned values are always around 20 - 30. Does someone know what do they mean? against which factor should it normalized?

```
// get the support vectors
    cv::Mat sv = svm->getSupportVectors();
    const int sv_total = sv.rows;
    // get the decision function
    cv::Mat alpha, svidx;
    double rho = svm->getDecisionFunction(0, alpha, svidx);
    std::vector< float > hog_detector(sv.cols + 1);
    memcpy(&hog_detector[0], sv.ptr(), sv.cols * sizeof(hog_detector[0]));
    hog_detector[sv.cols] = (float)-rho;


    //hog.winSize = cv::Size(64, 48);
    hog.setSVMDetector(hog_detector);

    //look for cars in an image:

    cv::Mat test_img = cv::imread(SCENE_IMG_PATH + "street_par150.jpg");
    cv::imwrite("result_1.jpg", test_img);

    std::vector<cv::Rect> obj_locations;
    std::vector<double> coinfidence_value;
    hog.detectMultiScale(test_img, obj_locations, coinfidence_value,0.00, cv::Size(4,4), cv::Size(0, 0), 1.05, 2.0, false);
    //what with normal?
    std::vector<cv::Point> obj_locs;
    std::vector<double> coinfidence_values;
    hog.detect(test_img, obj_locs,coinfidence_values, (0.0), cv::Size(4, 4), cv::Size(0,0));
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue after 5 years in Python binding.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://answers.opencv.org/question/56991/always-get-single-return-in-middle-of-image-with-custom-svm-using-hogdetectmultiscale/

Answer (score 0):

OK I resolved it for Linear SVMs. Since there's from none to barely some documentation about this, maybe it will be useful to somebody else, so: Here we go!

The problem was that the alphas and rhos were already multiplied by -1 internally, therefore, one needs to do this:

```
// get the support vectors
    cv::Mat sv = svm->getSupportVectors();
    sv = -sv;
    const int sv_total = sv.rows;
    // get the decision function
    cv::Mat alpha, svidx;
    double rho = svm->getDecisionFunction(0, alpha, svidx);
    std::vector< float > hog_detector(sv.cols + 1);
    memcpy(&hog_detector[0], sv.ptr(), sv.cols * sizeof(hog_detector[0]));
    hog_detector[sv.cols] = (float) rho;
```

Afterwards it does not work perfect but does what it is supposed to do and is extremelly fast in comparison with the "wrong" version.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet the same issue. No matter what test picture feeds in, the output always has a rectangular in the middle and the rectangular always appears at the same place.

I fixed it with David Romero's solution! Thanks a lot!

```
// get the support vectors
    cv::Mat sv = svm->getSupportVectors();
    sv = -sv;
    const int sv_total = sv.rows;
    // get the decision function
    cv::Mat alpha, svidx;
    double rho = svm->getDecisionFunction(0, alpha, svidx);
    std::vector< float > hog_detector(sv.cols + 1);
    memcpy(&hog_detector[0], sv.ptr(), sv.cols * sizeof(hog_detector[0]));
    hog_detector[sv.cols] = (float) rho;
```

It do work well!

Comment: Glad to hear that! It would be nice if you could mark the answer so that other people know it works ;)